# Binary Search Tree Print Range

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

So I have to modify the BST class to include a PrintRange function, which would essentially print all nodes between two values in order.

Here is the class

```
/** Source code example for "A Practical Introduction to Data
    Structures and Algorithm Analysis, 3rd Edition (Java)" 
    by Clifford A. Shaffer
    Copyright 2008-2011 by Clifford A. Shaffer
*/

import java.lang.Comparable;

/** Binary Search Tree implementation for Dictionary ADT */
class BST<Key extends Comparable<? super Key>, E>
         implements Dictionary<Key, E> {
  private BSTNode<Key,E> root; // Root of the BST
  int nodecount;             // Number of nodes in the BST

  /** Constructor */
  BST() { root = null; nodecount = 0; }

  /** Reinitialize tree */
  public void clear() { root = null; nodecount = 0; }

  /** Insert a record into the tree.
      @param k Key value of the record.
      @param e The record to insert. */
  public void insert(Key k, E e) {
    root = inserthelp(root, k, e);
    nodecount++;
  }

// Return root

  public BSTNode getRoot()
  {
   return root;
  }  

 /** Remove a record from the tree.
      @param k Key value of record to remove.
      @return The record removed, null if there is none. */

  public E remove(Key k) {
    E temp = findhelp(root, k);   // First find it
    if (temp != null) {
      root = removehelp(root, k); // Now remove it
      nodecount--;
    }
    return temp;
  }

  /** Remove and return the root node from the dictionary.
      @return The record removed, null if tree is empty. */
  public E removeAny() {
    if (root == null) return null;
    E temp = root.element();
    root = removehelp(root, root.key());
    nodecount--;
    return temp;
  }

  /** @return Record with key value k, null if none exist.
      @param k The key value to find. */
  public E find(Key k) { return findhelp(root, k); }

  /** @return The number of records in the dictionary. */
  public int size() { return nodecount; }

  private E findhelp(BSTNode<Key,E> rt, Key k) {
  if (rt == null) return null;
  if (rt.key().compareTo(k) > 0)
    return findhelp(rt.left(), k);
  else if (rt.key().compareTo(k) == 0) return rt.element();
  else return findhelp(rt.right(), k);
}
/** @return The current subtree, modified to contain
   the new item */
private BSTNode<Key,E> inserthelp(BSTNode<Key,E> rt,
                                  Key k, E e) {
  if (rt == null) return new BSTNode<Key,E>(k, e);
  if (rt.key().compareTo(k) > 0)
    rt.setLeft(inserthelp(rt.left(), k, e));
  else
    rt.setRight(inserthelp(rt.right(), k, e));
  return rt;
}
/** Remove a node with key value k
    @return The tree with the node removed */

 private BSTNode<Key,E> removehelp(BSTNode<Key,E> rt,Key k) {
  if (rt == null) return null;
  if (rt.key().compareTo(k) > 0)
    rt.setLeft(removehelp(rt.left(), k));
  else if (rt.key().compareTo(k) < 0)
    rt.setRight(removehelp(rt.right(), k));
  else { // Found it
    if (rt.left() == null) return rt.right();
    else if (rt.right() == null) return rt.left();
    else { // Two children
      BSTNode<Key,E> temp = getmin(rt.right());
      rt.setElement(temp.element());
      rt.setKey(temp.key());
      rt.setRight(deletemin(rt.right()));
    }
  }
  return rt;
}

private BSTNode<Key,E> getmin(BSTNode<Key,E> rt) {
  if (rt.left() == null) return rt;
  return getmin(rt.left());
}

private BSTNode<Key,E> deletemin(BSTNode<Key,E> rt) {
  if (rt.left() == null) return rt.right();
  rt.setLeft(deletemin(rt.left()));
  return rt;
}
  private void printhelp(BSTNode<Key,E> rt) {
    if (rt == null) return;
    printhelp(rt.left());
    printVisit(rt.element());
    printhelp(rt.right());
  }

  private StringBuffer out;

  public String toString() {
    out = new StringBuffer(400);
    printhelp(root);
    return out.toString();
  }
  private void printVisit(E it) {
    out.append(it + "\n");
  }

  public void printPreOrder(BSTNode<E, E> root) {
      if (root != null) {
          System.out.println(root.element());
          printPreOrder(root.left());
          printPreOrder(root.right());
      }
  }

  public void printInOrder(BSTNode<E, E> root) {
      if (root != null) {
          printInOrder(root.left());
          System.out.println(root.element());
          printInOrder(root.right());
      }
  }

  public void printPostOrder(BSTNode<E, E> root) {
      if (root != null) {
          printPostOrder(root.left());
          printPostOrder(root.right());
          System.out.println(root.element());
      }
  }

}
```

Here's what I have so far for the PrintRange function:

```
public void printRange(BSTNode<E, E> root, E low, E high) {
          if (root != null) {
            printRange(root.left(), low, high);
            if (root.element().toString().compareTo(low.toString()) > 0 && root.element().toString().compareTo(high.toString()) < 0)
              System.out.println(root.element());
            printRange(root.right(), low, high);
          }
      }
```

But it's giving me an error. Any suggestions on how to compare elements/nodes/I'm not even certain in a BST?

Here's the driver if it helps

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab8a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BST<String, String> tree = new BST<String, String>();
        Scanner fileScan = null, scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Open file
        try {
            fileScan = new Scanner(new File("inventory.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Reads elements from file
        while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = fileScan.nextLine();
            tree.insert(s, s);
        }

        System.out.println("\nRange");
        tree.printRange(tree.getRoot(), "A", "B");

    }

}
```

And the text file:

CT16C1288B

DT14B1225F

MI15B1250A

MI15B1251A

HO03N1095A

HY07D1095BQ

KI04D2593C

DG12A1240AQ

HY03G2593BQ

TO30A1310A

HO03N1095AQ

HO01H1351C

HO01H1350C

FT18A1288B

LR15A1000A

BM12E1000A

VW02B3113A

NI23H1230AQ

LX03D2503A

LX03D2502A

LX03D2502A

VW22A3113B

VW22B3113A

Comment: The reason you're getting an error is that your code is wrong.  If you want more specific information about where your code is wrong, please provide more specific information about the error instead of just "it's giving me an error".  We can't work with that.

Comment: I found the mistake. There was none. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken. There was no error. I must have fixed the code at some point.